# sigsetjmp() and siglongjmp(): The mask signals are not the same on call to sigsetjmp() and return of siglongjmp()

Tags: c, unix

**According to man page:**

If you want to portably save and restore signal masks, use `sigsetjmp()` and `siglongjmp()`.

`sigsetjmp()` is similar to `setjmp()`.  If, and only if, `savesigs` is nonzero, the process's current signal mask is saved in `env` and will
       be restored if a `siglongjmp(3)` is later performed with this `env`.

**But in my program** it is not true with above statements or I am missing something? The mask signals are not the same when `sigsetjmp` is called and when `siglongjmp` returns. I have written comments throughout the code to explain the question in detail. my question is why is it so?

Thanks in advanced

```
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

sigjmp_buf env;

static void handler(int signo)
      {
        printf("\ncatched signal: %d\n", signo);
        siglongjmp(env,1);
      }

int main(void)
   {
        struct sigaction action;

        action.sa_flags = 0;
        action.sa_handler = handler;

       if( (sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask) == -1) || (sigaction(SIGINT, &action, NULL) == -1) )
        {  
            perror("Failed to set!");
            return 1;
        }

       printf("this is process %ld\n", (long)getpid());

       //here I add the SIGSEGV to mask signals i.e action.sa_mask
       sigaddset(&action.sa_mask,SIGSEGV);
       sigaction(0, &action, NULL);
       sigaction(0, 0 , &action);
       printf("\nsigismember(&action.sa_mask, SIGSEGV)? 1 : 0 -> %d\n", sigismember(&action.sa_mask, SIGSEGV)? 1 : 0);
       //and yes it is member of mask signals i.e action.sa_mask

       if(sigsetjmp(env,1)) //"first time" it saves state of registers and mask signals and as return value is 0 it does not go inside
         {
            //when it comes here due to siglongjmp() the signal masks must be restored
            printf("Return to main loop due to ^c\n");

            //so again SIGSEGV must be member of mask signal i.e action.sa_mask as it was removed only after sigsetjmp was called
            sigaction(0 , 0 , &action);
            printf("sigismember(&action.sa_mask, SIGSEGV)? 1 : 0 -> %d\n", sigismember(&action.sa_mask, SIGSEGV)? 1 : 0);
            //but it shows it is NOT member of mask signal i.e action.sa_mask. why???
        }

    //here I delete the SIGSEGV from mask signals i.e action.sa_mask
    sigdelset(&action.sa_mask,SIGSEGV);
    sigaction(0, &action, NULL);
    sigaction(0, 0 , &action);

    printf("\nsigismember(&action.sa_mask, SIGSEGV)? 1 : 0 -> %d\n\n", sigismember(&action.sa_mask, SIGSEGV)? 1 : 0);

    for(;;);
}
```

**output:**

```
    majid@K53SC:~/Desktop$ ./a.out
    this is process 6335

    sigismember(&action.sa_mask, SIGSEGV)? 1 : 0 -> 1

    sigismember(&action.sa_mask, SIGSEGV)? 1 : 0 -> 0

    ^C
    catched signal: 2
    Return to main loop due to ^c
    sigismember(&action.sa_mask, SIGSEGV)? 1 : 0 -> 0

    sigismember(&action.sa_mask, SIGSEGV)? 1 : 0 -> 0

    ^C
    catched signal: 2
    Return to main loop due to ^c
    sigismember(&action.sa_mask, SIGSEGV)? 1 : 0 -> 0
    sigismember(&action.sa_mask, SIGSEGV)? 1 : 0 -> 0
```

**Edit**

I'm posting a **correct program** to show the concept of `sigsetjmp()` and `siglongjmp()` and `how the signal mask is restored` and it's output based on the answer Mr. Jean-Baptiste Yunès has given in the answer section so it may be helpful for others:

```
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

sigjmp_buf env;

void handler(int signo)
    {
      printf("\nCaught signal: %s", strsignal(signo));
      siglongjmp(env,1);
    }

int main(void)
   {
      sigset_t pmask;

      if( (sigemptyset(&pmask) == -1) || (signal(SIGINT, handler)== SIG_ERR) )
        {  
           perror("Failed to set!");
           return 1;
        }

    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &pmask, NULL); //set the process signal mask to pmask

    sigprocmask(0, NULL, &pmask);           //check the process mask in pmask
    printf("\nsigismember(&pmask, SIGSEGV)? 1 : 0 -> %d", sigismember(&pmask, SIGSEGV)? 1 : 0);


    if(sigsetjmp(env,1)!=0)    //save process environment context and signal mask
        printf("\nReturn from signal handler to main loop\nProcess signal mask is restored by siglongjmp()!\n");

    else
        printf("\nProcess signal mask is saved by sigsetjmp()!\n");

    printf("\n**** This is process %ld ****", (long)getpid());
    sigprocmask(0, NULL, &pmask);           //ckeck the process mask to mask
    printf("\nsigismember(&pmask, SIGSEGV)? 1 : 0 -> %d", sigismember(&pmask, SIGSEGV)? 1 : 0);

    printf("\nChanging process signal mask");
    sigaddset(&pmask,SIGSEGV);
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &pmask, NULL);

    sigprocmask(0, NULL, &pmask);           //ckeck the process mask to mask
    printf("\nsigismember(&pmask, SIGSEGV)? 1 : 0 -> %d\n\n", sigismember(&pmask, SIGSEGV)? 1 : 0);

    pause();
}
```

**Output**

```
majid@K53SC:~/Desktop$ gcc P45.c
majid@K53SC:~/Desktop$ ./a.out

sigismember(&pmask, SIGSEGV)? 1 : 0 -> 0
Process signal mask is saved by sigsetjmp()!

**** This is process 23099 ****
sigismember(&pmask, SIGSEGV)? 1 : 0 -> 0
Changing process signal mask
sigismember(&pmask, SIGSEGV)? 1 : 0 -> 1

^C
Caught signal: Interrupt
Return from signal handler to main loop
Process signal mask is restored by siglongjmp()!

**** This is process 23099 ****
sigismember(&pmask, SIGSEGV)? 1 : 0 -> 0
Changing process signal mask
sigismember(&pmask, SIGSEGV)? 1 : 0 -> 1
```

Comment: BTW: `printf("\ncatched signal: %d\n", signo);` You should not call printf() and friends from within a signal handler.

Comment: @wildplasser Yes correct, Thank you, but that makes no difference on the output of the program.

Comment: You seem to be trying to call `sigaction(0, ...)` to do something, but that is meaningless.  `0` is not a valid signal number, so those calls will just fail (with `EINVAL`) and won't do anything.  What are you trying to do with them?

Comment: @Chris yes as you say it is meaningless, but changing it to any other valid number also will have the same result. anyway the solution was given by Mr. Jean-Baptiste Yunès as you can see in updated result. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you don't print the right information. You just print the `action.sa_mask` which is correct behavior, because you changed it by removing `SIGSEGV` from it.

What you want is to print the process mask available through `sigprocmask`, this is the value saved by `sigsetjmp`/`siglongjmp`.

-----EDIT----------------------------

From `sigprocmask` manual (GNU) :

> The collection of signals that are currently blocked is called the
>   signal mask. Each process has its own signal mask. When you create a
>   new process (see Creating a Process), it inherits its parent’s mask.
>   You can block or unblock signals with total flexibility by modifying
>   the signal mask.

This mask is the one that is restored through `siglongjmp` calls.

From `sigaction` manual (GNU) about `sa_mask` field:

> This specifies a set of signals to be blocked while the handler runs.
>   Blocking is explained in Blocking for Handler. Note that the signal
>   that was delivered is automatically blocked by default before its
>   handler is started; this is true regardless of the value in sa_mask.
>   If you want that signal not to be blocked within its handler, you must
>   write code in the handler to unblock it.

So, using `sigaction` does not modify the process mask, but will modify it **when an handler will be executed at some signal delivery**.

Comment: I have used  sigaction(0, 0 , &action); before printing so action holds the current values of process at that point of code not the old values

Comment: @Jean_Baptiste I even tried using sigprocmask() but output is the same

Comment: May you please explain more if I am missing something. what exactly should I use to show/print the signal mask status would be same as the time of sigsetjmp() as I have used sigprocmask but output is the same. If it is not so much to ask, may you please post the modified code to show so. Regards

Comment: You never modified the process mask, so you can't observe its modification. What you modified is the mask that will be set during signal delivery and unset on handler's return, so your code actually can't observe anything.  `sigaction` do not modify the process mask. Try set a mask before `sigsetjmp` and then after... You will be able to observe the reset of it.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir, I'll try it and post the result. Thank you

Comment: Thank you soooo much, It worked :) it was such an awesome moment seeing the correct output as I have been working on it for last two days. :)